# C# How to update bool in a database a sql query

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox

How to update bool in a database a sql query

below is the code i have but i am unsure of how to implement the checkbox.
Thank you for any help.

i have updated the code to remove the sql injection problems.

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From ", comboBox1.Text), con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
string tableName = comboBox1.Text.ToString();

cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [" + tableName + "] SET"
    +"People_Call_Status = @People_Call_Status,"
    +"Research_Date=@Research_Date,"
    + "tblCompanies_Area_Dialling_Code = @tblCompanies_Area_Dialling_Code,"
    + "Work_Number = @Work_Number,"
    + "building_Address = @building_Address,"
    + "[Street Address] = @[Street Address],"
    + "suburb = @suburb,"
    + "city = @city,"
    + "res_Code = @res_Code,"
    + "industry_Vertical_ID = @industry_Vertical_ID,"
    + "pO_Box = @pO_Box,"
    + "post_Office = @post_Office,"
    + "postal_Code = @postal_Code,"
    + "country_ID = @country_ID,"
    + "province_ID = @province_ID," //this line
    + "prospect = @prospect"
    + "WHERE Company_ID = @Company_ID ";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@People_Call_Status", Status_textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Research_Date", Date_textBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_Name", company_NameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblCompanies_Area_Dialling_Code", tblCompanies_Area_Dialling_CodeTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_Number", work_NumberTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@building_Address", building_AddressTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Street Address]", street_AddressTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", suburbTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res_Code", res_CodeTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@industry_Vertical_ID", industry_Vertical_IDTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pO_Box", pO_BoxTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post_Office", post_OfficeTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postal_Code", postal_CodeTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_ID", country_IDTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province_ID", province_IDTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prospect", prospectCheckBox.Checked);                                     
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_ID", company_IDTextBox.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: 1. Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. 2 "Is not working" is not a valid description of the problem you are facing, help us help you by carefully describing what you want...

Comment: The `Checked` property is a `bool`. Is the `prospect` column in your also a bool or bit type? If so try removing the ' before and after adding the Checked property to the statement. And as @Adimeus said you code is vulnerable to SQL Injections, try using Parameters.

Comment: so there is no way for you to help me how to update a bool value in a database?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, `bool` is mapped as a `bit` datatype with `0` and `1` values.

So what you need to do is:

```
"', prospect = '" + prospectCheckBox.Checked ? 1 : 0
```

**Side-Note:**

Don't concatenate strings to build up your query from user data input, this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead, use parameterized queries or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

What DBMS platform are you using, and can you show the DDL for the table?

I can't guarantee this will work, but instead of using `AddWithValue` try using the `Add` method with explicit types declared:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@People_Call_Status", OleDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Research_Date", OleDbType.VarChar));
...
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@prospect", OleDbType.Boolean));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Company_ID", OleDbType.VarChar));

cmd.Parameters[0].Value = Status_textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = Date_textBox.Text;
...
cmd.Parameters[16].Value = prospectCheckBox.Checked;
cmd.Parameters[17].Value = company_IDTextBox.Text;
```

Also, with regards to SQL Injection, you still have a theoretical vulnerability:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [" + tableName + "] SET"
    + "People_Call_Status = @People_Call_Status,"
    + "Research_Date=@Research_Date,"
    ...
    + "prospect = @prospect"
    + "WHERE Company_ID = @Company_ID ";
```

I realize it's an obscure possibility, but if the `tableName` variable were to contain this string or something like it:

```
Table1 set foo = 'bar';
truncate table ba2;
update table3
```

You could see how it would compile, execute and do something other than what you had in mind.  Again, I realize this is reaching, and your input does come from a combo box, but it's still a theoretical risk.